# Try and catch problems

Tags: java

I am trying to write a ' try and catch ' method in this example, but for some reason I'm getting in error on all of my variables saying; "cannot find symbol". This is happening in all instances of:
subtotal &
customerType. Does anyone know what can be causing this?

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class InvoiceApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {
        // get the input from the user
        try
        {    
        //System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c): ");
            String customerType = getValidCustomerType(sc);
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
            double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            sc.next();
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid number. Try again \n");
            continue;
        }

        // get the discount percent
        double discountPercent = 0;
        if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 100)
                discountPercent = 0;
            else if (subtotal >= 100 && subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .1;
            else if (subtotal >= 250)
                discountPercent = .2;
        }
        else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .2;
            else
                discountPercent = .3;
        }
        else
        {
            discountPercent = .1;
        }

        // calculate the discount amount and total
        double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
        double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

        // format and display the results
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        System.out.println(
                "Discount percent: " + percent.format(discountPercent) + "\n" +
                "Discount amount:  " + currency.format(discountAmount) + "\n" +
                "Total:            " + currency.format(total) + "\n");

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the scope of your variables: if you declare something in a `try` block, it is visible only within that `try` block; it is not going to be visible outside the `try` block, including even the `catch` blocks after it.

In order to get around this problem, declare the variable outside the `try` block:

```
String customerType;
double subtotal;
try {    
//System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c): ");
    customerType = getValidCustomerType(sc);
    System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
    subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Error! Invalid number. Try again \n");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Now it's tell me that: customerType = getValidCustomerType is invalid.
Do I need to set up another static method for the try and catch to properly work?

Answer (score 1):

You declare `subtotal` and `customerType` in try block, so that variable only visible in try block.

Change your code like this will fix the problem:

```
double subtotal = 0;
String customerType = "";
try
{    
        //System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c): ");
        String customerType = getValidCustomerType(sc);
        System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
        subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
}
catch (InputMismatchException e)
{
        sc.next();
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid number. Try again \n");
        continue;
}
```

More : [Blocks and Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html)

Comment: I hate to be a stickler but your code didn't fix the issue, I can 'useful' it, but the other answer was what solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You declared subtotal and customertype inside the brackets of the try {}.  That is the only place where they are valid.  If you declared them before the try this would have been fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static String getValidCustomerType(Scanner sc)
{
    String customerType = "";
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c): ");
        customerType = sc.next();
        if  (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("c")))
        isValid = true;            
       else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid customer type. Try again. \n");
        }    
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    return customerType;
}
}
```